# AJAXify won't work on phpBB?

Tags: ajax, phpbb, phpbb3, ajaxify

According to PHPBB's website AJAXify is enabled on the software however I can not get it to work at all.

I have followed their insturctions documented on their website here: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Using_AJAX

Here is my code:

```
<form action="{S_LOGIN_ACTION}" method="post" id="login" data-ajax="true">
```

I have the latest version of the jQuery library enabled (2.1.1) loaded and jJavaScript enabled.

What could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am running phpBB 3.0.12 (the latest stable release)

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the AJAXify features are only available on php 3.1 which isn't stable yet :)